# Are questions about frameworks sometimes more common than questions about the language?

Tags: discussion

On Stack Overflow as of 19 August 2011 , [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) has 28K questions, while [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) has 47K questions, and once you exclude those that have both, you have 16K versus 34K, ie the language tag has fewer than half the questions that the framework has.

Is this unique to Ruby, or does this happen to other languages as well?

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @Michael: If Ruby is the programming language for which this happens, then it may indicate that the Ruby ecosystem may have some problems.

Comment: Or just a really popular framework?

Comment: You also have to consider people who mistag questions. Like there are lots of questions about the .NET Framework that have only the `[c#]` tag because that's the first thing that came to the mind of the asker. I don't see how this question is productive or useful, though.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Do you think the question's unsuitable for any SE site, or do you think it's better suited to a different one than meta?

Comment: Erm, I don't think it's necessarily *unsuitable*. There's nothing wrong with asking it here. I just don't know what the point is. What good is this data going to do you?

Comment: @Cody: I feel it's good to get numerical data to confirm or deny a gut feeling.

Comment: I think the data confirms it's unique to ruby, but I don't think it means ruby is unhealthy -- there are still more ruby-but-not-ruby-on-rails questions than there are perl questions, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at each language tag, and then went to the top few tags that were framework-like. This is total tags, not overlap or unique. I didn't attempt to categorize iPhone or Android questions.

[python](/questions/tagged/python) 70,179 [django](/questions/tagged/django) 21,775 [google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) 7,328 (includes Java version)

[php](/questions/tagged/php) 138,670 [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) 8,955 [zend-framework](/questions/tagged/zend-framework) 7,510 [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) 5,599

[java](/questions/tagged/java) 149,995 [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) 9,045 [jsp](/questions/tagged/jsp) 6,531

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) 207,260 [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) 88,339 [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) 87,495 [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) 25,790

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) 50,334 [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) 13,256

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) 122,713 [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) 106,063

So,[ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) has more questions than any other framework except [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) / [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) or [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), on the other hand, has far less questions than any of these other languages.

> Is this unique to Ruby, or does this happen to other languages as well? – @Andrew Grimm

It's unique to Ruby, at least among the languages popular on this site.

> Or just a really popular framework? – @Michael Mrozek

It's a really popular framework.

> If Ruby is the programming language for which this happens, then it may indicate that the Ruby ecosystem may have some problems. – @Andrew Grimm

I don't think we can rule one way or the other on this, based on this information. The "really popular framework" theory seems sufficient. There are also more [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) -[ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) questions than there are [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) questions, for example.

Comment: You really should have compared [c#] to [.net]. The latter is actually the framework - and many .NET questions are quite incorrectly tagged [c#] instead.

Comment: Adding it. It basically has the same number of q's as asp.net; the sum of the two (even counting double-tagged questions twice) still doesn't add up to the # of q's for C#.

Comment: Even `javascript` beats `jquery`! Although it's fairly close. (120K vs. 100K)

Comment: Added. Fairly similar to the C# vs. .net+asp.net ratio (there is very little overlap between .net and asp.net)

Comment: Also, a better comparison for the [objective-c] (50,334) tag is vs. [iphone] at (94,880).  Almost all of the latter questions use the Objective-C language, yet it isn't always specified in the tags.  Nominally, these would be tagged [cocoa-touch], but that hasn't been the convention for this platform.

Comment: I think iPhone and Android are special cases. This was _really_ about web frameworks anyway; I just threw a couple of others in for completeness.